# Creating named range based on value in column

Tags: excel, vba, named-ranges

I want to create a named range based on the value in column B.

For example
[image]

I want to create

- range with name: UNIT21, and from the data above the RefersTo should be A2:C4 and A6:C6.
- range with name: UNIT22 for data with 22 in its column B.

1. How do I select the whole row from A:C for respective row?
2. How do I add new data to existing named range instead of replacing the existing value like my code is does.

```vb
Sub naming()
    Dim row_index As Long
    Dim lastrow As Long: lastrow = 5
    
    Dim NamedRange As Range
    Dim celltomap As Range
    
    Dim Rng As Range
    
    For row_index = 1 To lastrow
    
        RangeName = Sheet3.Range("A2:C6").Cells(row_index, 2).Value
        Set celltomap = Sheet3.Range("A2:C6").Cells(row_index, 3)
        
        Sheet3.Names.Add Name:="UNIT" & RangeName, RefersTo:=celltomap
     
        MsgBox ("UNIT" & RangeName)
    
    Next row_index
    
End Sub
```

[cross-posted](https://www.ozgrid.com/forum/index.php?thread/1226181-create-named-range-based-on-value-in-column/)

Comment: Sounds great. Please include the code you are using to do that in your question and explain the problems that you are running into.

Comment: @Nazirah Zainal can you please also include a snapshot of your excel worksheet. Your question is still not clear to me

Comment: @MRah added a snapshot of the worksheet & added some info. I hope the question is clear now :)

Comment: @Davesexcel Ah i edited the code to make it simpler in the question. Missed it. Changed it with some word and number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run the below code, it will create the range names.

The value of the named ranges will be  {...}  if the list is unsorted before you run the code.

```
Sub NameRanges()

    Dim cUnique As Collection
    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim Cell As Range
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim vNum As Variant
    Dim FrstRng As Range
    Dim UnionRng As Range
    Dim c As Range

    Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    With sh
        Set Rng = .Range("B2:B" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row)
        Set cUnique = New Collection

        On Error Resume Next
        For Each Cell In Rng.Cells
            cUnique.Add Cell.Value, CStr(Cell.Value)
        Next Cell
        On Error GoTo 0

        For Each vNum In cUnique
            For Each c In Rng.Cells
                If c = vNum Then
                    If Not UnionRng Is Nothing Then
                        Set UnionRng = Union(UnionRng, c.Offset(, 1))   'adds to the range
                    Else
                        Set UnionRng = c.Offset(, 1)
                    End If
                End If
            Next c

            UnionRng.Name = "Unit" & vNum
            Set UnionRng = Nothing
        Next vNum
    End With

End Sub
```

There may be a time you want to delete the range names and start over.

```
Sub delete_RngNames()
    Dim rn As Name
    For Each rn In ActiveWorkbook.Names
        rn.Delete
    Next rn
End Sub
```

You did not indicate an ActiveX combobox on the worksheet or a UserForm.

This should work for both, just the buttonNames might be different.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim s As String, rng As Range, c As Range

    s = "Unit" & Me.TextBox1

    Me.ComboBox1.Clear

    For Each c In Range(s).Cells
        Me.ComboBox1.AddItem c
    Next c

End Sub
```

This code assumes you have entered something in a textbox. Combining "Unit" & the textbox  will indicate what range to populate the combobox

Comment: Thank you! It works. If the named ranges become {...}, how do I modify it to use the named range in combobox?

Comment: can I know what does the cUnique/collection refers to?

Comment: Since a collection cannot have the same items, when you add something to a collection, just the unique items are stored. The code first loops through the range to find the unique items, then loops to create the range names.

Comment: I have edited code for combobox according to my need. Thank you! Last question, if the data is unsorted and the named range becomes {...}, can we use the named range as a list for combobox?

Comment: I don't believe so, if you manually go into the combobox properties, and enter the list as a non contiguous  range it will not let you.

Comment: I see. I automatically sorted my data and create named range based on your code, and populate the combobox.

Answer (score 0):

this should do:

```
Option Explicit

Sub naming()
    Dim row_index As Long
    Dim lastrow As Long: lastrow = 5

    Dim celltomap As Range
    Dim RangeName As String
    Dim nm As Name

    For row_index = 1 To lastrow
        RangeName = Foglio1.Range("A2:C6").Cells(row_index, 2).Value
        Set celltomap = Foglio1.Range("A2:C6").Cells(row_index, 3)

        On Error Resume Next
        Set nm = Foglio1.Names("UNIT" & RangeName)
        On Error GoTo 0

        If nm Is Nothing Then ' first time you hit "UNIT" & RangeName -> set a new name
            Foglio1.Names.Add Name:="UNIT" & RangeName, RefersTo:=celltomap
        Else ' name already there -> update its 'RefersTo' property
            nm.RefersTo = Union(nm.RefersToRange, celltomap)
        End If
        Set nm = Nothing ' initialize 'nm' for subsequent 'If nm Is Nothing Then' check
    Next
End Sub
```

As you see I stuck to your original `celltomap` setting pattern, i.e.: only column "C" cells, but you can easily twink the code and expand to more columns

Comment: It does the work! Thanks. However, the value of the named range becomes {...} rather than the words in column C itself. As I want to use this named range in combobox, error occurred. Any ideas?