# Value of named range becomes {...}

Tags: excel, vba, range

Based on [Creating named range based on value in column](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59006163/12420134),

```
Option Explicit

Sub naming()
    Dim row_index As Long
    Dim lastrow As Long: lastrow = 5

    Dim celltomap As Range
    Dim RangeName As String
    Dim nm As Name

    For row_index = 1 To lastrow
        RangeName = Foglio1.Range("A2:C6").Cells(row_index, 2).Value
        Set celltomap = Foglio1.Range("A2:C6").Cells(row_index, 3)

        On Error Resume Next
        Set nm = Foglio1.Names("UNIT" & RangeName)
        On Error GoTo 0

        If nm Is Nothing Then ' first time you hit "UNIT" & RangeName -> set a new name
            Foglio1.Names.Add Name:="UNIT" & RangeName, RefersTo:=celltomap
        Else ' name already there -> update its 'RefersTo' property
            nm.RefersTo = Union(nm.RefersToRange, celltomap)
        End If
        Set nm = Nothing ' initialize 'nm' for subsequent 'If nm Is Nothing Then' check
    Next
End Sub
```

I want to create named range that contains data from column C, based on column B value. When column B is 21, it will create Named Range : UNIT21 with: great, sew, test, random in it.

[Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HKOfJ.jpg) [Value of Named Range](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ol2E9.jpg)
From the named range created, I would like to use it in combobox. However, the value of named range becomes {...} (i tried googling what it means, and cannot find what it is). So, the combobox appear blank.

What am I expecting is it to be {"great";"sew";"test";"random"} for UNIT 21.

1. What does {...} mean?
2. Any ideas on how to fix this? - {...} to {"xx";"xy"}. Why combobox becomes blank.

Thank you.

Comment: {...} means that you got an array with text data. You should return the values of the array as you can not return the array itself. Check on [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/concepts/getting-started/using-arrays)

Comment: @DavidGarcíaBodego so, I am returning the whole array? So, I should assign celltomap as variant, which then becomes array, rather than range? Is the data in text array. should i do split..  Not sure how to move on.

Comment: The arrays are handling just returning as `Name_of_array`(index). So if your array is called DATA, the first element is DATA(0), then DATA(1)... and so on.

Comment: How do i extract the data from array? As shown above, the value of my named range UNIT 21 is {...}. so in order to extract, I used UNIT21(1). However, it does not  produce the first value in the array {...} . and gives me #REF! .